# OSM tile server can not start up due to an error in OSMBright.xml

Tags: openstreetmap, tile-server

I followed the [guide](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/manually-building-a-tile-server-14-04/) from osm in order to get a tile server running.
But I do get the following errors:

```
     An error occurred while loading the map layer 'default': 
    Could not create datasource for type: ''  encountered during parsing of layer 'land-low' in Layer at line 117 
    of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'renderd[6906]: An error occurred while loading the map 
    layer 'default': 
    Could not create datasource. 
    Required parameter 'type' is missing  encountered during parsing of layer 'land-low' in 
    Layer at line 117 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'
    renderd[6906]: 
    An error occurred while loading the map layer

 'default': Could not create datasource. 
Required parameter 'type' is missing  encountered during parsing of layer 'land-low' in Layer at line 117 of '/usr/local/share/maps/style/OSMBright/OSMBright.xml'
```

I checked several other solutions without success.

Why is type missing?it is definitely defined in osm-bright/osm-bright.osm2pgsql.mml

```
"file": "/usr/local/share/maps/style/osm-bright-master/shp/land-polygons-split-3857/land_polygons.shp",
        "srs": "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over",
        "type": "shape"
```

also defined in the OSMBright.xml

```
<Layer name="land-low"
  status="on"
  srs="+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over">
    <StyleName>land-low</StyleName>
    <Datasource>
       <Parameter name="dbname"><![CDATA[osm]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="extent"><![CDATA[-20037508.34 -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="file"><![CDATA[/usr/local/share/maps/style/osm-bright-master/shp/simplified-land-polygons-complete-3857/simplified_land_polygons.shp]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="srs"><![CDATA[+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0.0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +wktext +no_defs +over]]></Parameter>
       <Parameter name="type"><![CDATA[shape]]></Parameter>
    </Datasource>
  </Layer>
```

Comment: Poosible duplicate of http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154337/starting-tile-sever-rendering-error-osmbright-xml

Comment: @AndreJ The solutions provided in the referenced duplicate are not working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Starting Tile Sever Rendering Error: OSMBright.xml](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/154337/starting-tile-sever-rendering-error-osmbright-xml)